# Android Changing Fragments Views when another fragment is clicked

Tags: android, view, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have 2 fragments. I d like to accomplish the following. When the View1 in FragmentA is clicked, I d like the Fragment B to look like this:

[Scenario 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4XJw.png)

And when the View2 in FragmentA is clicked, I d like to get this:

[Scenario 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjWls.png)

The imageView s in FragmentB should be loaded with different images of course in both scenarios.

I was able to transfer data from A to B through an interface (A->Main Activity->B). But the problem is and I think this is the key Part, **when I get back to Fragment B, the LinearLayout which holds the ImageViews does not exist(findViewById on a null object error)!**

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: r u using add method getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.cnt, new FragmentB ()).commit();

Comment: No, I dont use that. But just to understand, I have a incomingCategory(String category) function and it gets called due to the onClick. So 2 questions:

1) Should I use your suggestion in the incomingCategory() function?

2) Wouldnt this create a new fragment? I dont want to do that. I just want to detach the imageView1 on FragmentB and add the imageView1, 2 and 3.